# Intercepting Campaign Product List Changes

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I've been looking for a way to keep in sync two campaign product lists. I haven't found a message to intercept when a product is added to or removed from a campaign list.

CampaignItem, the intersect entity used for the N:N campaign-product relationship (among others), cannot be used as a target of a plugin step.

What are my options here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use Campaign AddItem / RemoveItem messages to track updates to Campaign http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959366.aspx

Comment: Thanks paramosh. I feel this is what I've been looking for. I'm going to verify the suggestion and then accept the answer.